# Events not showed with the correct StartDate and EndDate

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4, extensible

This is the returned Json:

```
{
"success":true,
"evts":[{
    "EventId":"1",
    "CalendarId":"2",
    "Title":"today2",
    "StartDate":"2013-05-01 10:00:00",
    "EndDate":"2013-05-03 02:00:00",
    "Duration":"0",
    "Location":"",
    "Notes":"",
    "Url":"",
    "IsAllDay":"0",
    "Reminder":"",
    "RRule":""
},{
    "EventId":"2",
    "CalendarId":"1",
    "Title":"today",
    "StartDate":"2013-05-15 00:00:00",
    "EndDate":"2013-05-19 00:00:00",
    "Duration":"0",
    "Location":"",
    "Notes":"",
    "Url":"",
    "IsAllDay":"0",
    "Reminder":"",
    "RRule":""
}]
}
```

But the calendar is showed like so:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/922537611.png

It shoulds be showed like so:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/358017742.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing 'Duration'?

'Cos on what I interpret on your JSON, StartDate and EndDate is already defined, so there is no need for the Duration.

Maybe that's what is messing with your calendar